# Datagridview error : Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to populate data in DataGridView control. It gets populated into it. But when I try to scroll down it gives me an exception like;

> Value of '352' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between
>   'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter name: Value

```
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.set_Value(Int32 value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ScrollRows(Int32 rowCount, Int32 deltaY, ScrollEventType scrollEventType)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ScrollRowsByCount(Int32 rows, ScrollEventType scrollEventType)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ? 
I am using DataSource property and not Rows.add()

Thanks in advance

Comment: The ScrollBar values are being exceeded. Are you using events for the ScrollBar? Please share the code you have used for the scrollbar

Comment: Does a call to `dataGridView1.PerformLayout()` fix this ? Please post some code

Comment: yes, it got resolved using PerformLayout()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It got resolved by dataGridView1.PerformLayout() after populating data.

Answer (score -1):

The similar kind of problem was faced by me too recently , I was using datagridview for entering the data in my database , everything worked fine but whenever I try to edit the data then it throws exception the moment I crossed 18 th row . The solution to this problem is use dgv.PerformLayout(); , call to this function will resolve the problem and exception wont be thrown

Comment: This is exactly the previously posted and accepted answer?