# Datagridview error : Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum' - dataGridView1.PerformLayout() does no work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am having troubles with datagridview when I want to have data partialy loaded and load next/previous data by scrolling (putting scrollbar with mouse to limit positions also).

This topic is much discussed, but mostly suggested answer "adding dataGridView1.PerformLayout()" does not works for me ([Datagridview error : Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440275/datagridview-error-value-should-be-between-minimum-and-maximum/7494629)).

Due to this, I have created simple test form only with datagridview, code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewTester
{
    public delegate void DeleteTableDelegate(DataGridView table);
    public delegate void FillRowsDelegate(DataGridView table, int rowsToAdd);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        VScrollBar vScrollbar;
        int index = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vScrollbar = dataGridView1.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First();

            vScrollbar.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(this.scrollbarValue_Changed);
            AppendRange(dataGridView1, 100);

        }

        public void ClearTableContents(DataGridView table)
        {
             //For calling from different threads
             if (table.InvokeRequired)
             {
                 var d = new DeleteTableDelegate(ClearTableContents);
                 table.Invoke(d, new object[] { table });
                 return;
             }
            
            try
            {
                table?.Rows.Clear();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
           
            table?.PerformLayout();
        }

        public void AppendRange(DataGridView table, int rowsToAdd)
        {
            if (table.InvokeRequired)
            {
                var d = new FillRowsDelegate(AppendRange);
                table.Invoke(d, new object[] { table, rowsToAdd });
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(rowsToAdd);
            DataGridViewRow[] dataGridViewRows = new DataGridViewRow[(rowsToAdd < 0 ? -rowsToAdd : rowsToAdd)];
            index = (rowsToAdd >= 0) ? (index ) : (index - 2*rowsToAdd);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewRows.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridViewRows[i] = new DataGridViewRow();
                dataGridViewRows[i].CreateCells(dataGridView1, new object[] { index + i, dataGridViewRows[i].GetHashCode() });
            }
            index = (rowsToAdd >= 0) ? (index+ rowsToAdd) : (index);

            table?.Rows.AddRange(dataGridViewRows);
            table?.PerformLayout();
        }

        private void scrollbarValue_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (vScrollbar.Visible)
            {
                if (vScrollbar.Value + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1) >= vScrollbar.Maximum)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Get NEXT results " + vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));

                    try
                    {
                        ClearTableContents(dataGridView1);
                        Console.WriteLine("CLEARED " + vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));
                        AppendRange(dataGridView1, 1); //Append it to Grid
                        Console.WriteLine("APENDED " + vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));

                    }
                    catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    }

                    System.Console.WriteLine(vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));
                }
                else if (vScrollbar.Value <= vScrollbar.Minimum)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Get PREVIOUS results " + vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));


                    try
                    {
                        ClearTableContents(dataGridView1);
                        Console.WriteLine("CLEARED " + vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));
                        AppendRange(dataGridView1, -1); //Append it to Grid
                        Console.WriteLine("APENDED " + vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));
                        dataGridView1?.PerformLayout();
                    }
                    catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    }


                    System.Console.WriteLine(vScrollbar.Maximum + ">=" + vScrollbar.Value + ">=" + vScrollbar.Minimum + " Large change -1 = " + (vScrollbar.LargeChange - 1));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

**EDIT:** This behaviour is caused holding scrollbar by mouse. If this paging is mapped to PageDown and PageUp buttons, there are no errors.

Comment: You should use your DataGridView in [VirtualMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode) to handle pagination, not trying to control the scrollbars.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for answer, but I think, I am looking for something different. I think, I have problems with scrollbar value when I remove entire contents and then put new contents.  Maybe I should pause it like rows: datagridview1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;